# Find next node using the class name from given node(javascript)?

Tags: javascript

For example

```
    <div class="descendants" style="width:500px;">div (current element) 
      <p>p (child)
        <span class="testclass">span (grandchild)</span>     
      </p>
      <p>p (child)
        <span>span (grandchild)</span>
      </p> 
    </div>
    <p class="testclass">This is paragraph</p>
   <div class="descendants" style="width:500px;">div (current element) 
      <p>p (child)
        <span>span (grandchild)</span>     
      </p>
      <p>p (child)
        <span>span (grandchild)</span>
      </p> 
    </div>
```

This the sample code . I have a node `<span class="testclass">span (grandchild)</span>` i need to find the next node which has same class name `testclass` using javascript.

Comment: What have you tried so far yourself?

Comment: When you say you have that node, how do you have it? Has it been clicked on, or have you selected it somehow? Seeing the JS code you have now would help a lot here

Comment: you can use as $('.testclass:eq(0)').next()

Comment: i get the node when click that  text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `$(this).closest('.descendants').next('.testclass').text()` .You should target with last  parent using [`closest()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj2-qLD_ofUAhUElZQKHcvnA_YQFgi_ATAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fclosest%2F&usg=AFQjCNGkhpVv76EWvWWYjEID4qvdUghHMQ) .Then apply with [`next()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiCy-PM_ofUAhVMFJQKHYVNAqsQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fnext%2F&usg=AFQjCNE498BhQOD1vTQGmOyAhS4eKba-Pw).its target with next `p.testclass`

```js
$('.testclass').eq(0).click(function(){
console.log($(this).closest('.descendants').next('.testclass').text())

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="descendants" style="width:500px;">div (current element)
  <p>p (child)
    <span class="testclass">span (grandchild)</span>
  </p>
  <p>p (child)
    <span>span (grandchild)</span>
  </p>
</div>
<p class="testclass">This is paragraph</p>
<div class="descendants" style="width:500px;">div (current element)
  <p>p (child)
    <span>span (grandchild)</span>
  </p>
  <p>p (child)
    <span>span (grandchild)</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: can u do it using pure javascript

Comment: For why ? you are mention a `jquery` tag also